# More than one footnote for same line?

Tags: footnotes

I am working on a price list. On the price list I have a column for the name of the model and a second column for a specification.

Currently I have an asterisk on each model. I also have a footnote (1) next to each specification.

I have to add another note related to TWO models only in the list I have (out of eight). Someone told me to add a NEW note with two asterisks but I cannot because at the bottom of the price list we have another note with two asterisks for something else on that sheet. Please see below a simplified example.

If I keep the asterisk in the first table and add a NEW note for Apple and Banana, how do I go about doing this? FYI - we did not use numbered footnotes originally for all footnotes because the number and product name together are confusing. (Product model name includes numbers).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are many symbols you can use as footnote markers.
According to wikipedia*, the traditional order of use in English is  *, †, ‡, §, ‖, ¶

* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Note_(typography)

Comment: okay, thanks! I was wondering if I could add the "dagger" or if that would be too many symbols..

Comment: @Ruby If the extra footnote for "Apple" is in addition to the footnote that's already there (instead of a replacement), then I think it would make sense to use the dagger as symbol for the second footnote. Because using both a single and double asterisk would easily be confused for a triple asterisk. 
On the other hand, if it's a replacement footnote, then you could also consider first changing triple asterisks to quadruple, double to triple, and then use double in the first table.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! :)

Comment: +1 for using a footnote in an answer about footnotes

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the number of symbols that are used for footnotes is limited. If the number of footnotes in a single page becomes large, then you may want to resolve to any of the following alternatives:

1. superscript numbers<sup>1</sup>
2. superscript letters<sup>a</sup>
3. numbers between square brackets [1]